# SKI combinator calculus of `2 = λf.λx.f(f x)`

Tags: lambda-calculus

EDIT: refactored this question into a slightly different, but related one: [Rules for converting lambda calculus expressions to SKI combinator calculus expression? Which rule(s) is/are incorrect?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4304294/rules-for-converting-lambda-calculus-expressions-to-ski-combinator-calculus-expr)

---

[learnxinyminutes.com](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/lambda-calculus/) defines $I$, $K$, and $S$ as follows:

```
I x = x
K x y = x
S x y z = x z (y z)
```

Then they give the following correspondences to aid in the conversion between lambda calculus and SKI combinator calculus:

1. `λx.x = I`
2. `λx.c = Kc`
3. `λx.(y z) = S (λx.y) (λx.z)`

They mention $2 = \lambda f.\lambda x.f(fx)$, and then proceed to convert the "inner part", i.e. $\lambda x.f(fx)$, into the equivalent SKI combinator calculus as follows:

```
  λx.f(f x)
= S (λx.f) (λx.(f x))          (case 3) <- mistake???
= S (K f)  (S (λx.f) (λx.x))   (case 2, 3)
= S (K f)  (S (K f) I)         (case 2, 1)
```

Have they made a mistake? When using `3.` they are taking `f x`, equating it to `z` in `λx.(y z) = S (λx.y) (λx.z)`, and then getting `S (λx.f) (λx.(f x))`, but that seems off since `x` is now a bound variable in `(λx.(f x))` when it shouldn't be?

---

Is this the correct way:

```
  λx.f(f x)
= S (λx.f) (λx.(f a))          (relabel x to a to avoid conflict, case 3)
= S (K f)  (S (λx.f) (λx.a))   (case 2, 3)
= S (K f)  (S (K f) (K a))     (case 2, 2)
```

---

Which is correct?

---

Indeed, could their `3.` be elaborated on further as follows to employ the kestrel, $K$:

3'. `λx.(y z) = S (λx.y) (λx.z) = S (Ky) (Kz)`?

If we include a `4.` as:

4. `K(c d) = λx.(c d) = S (Kc) (Kd)` (apply `2.` then `3'.`)

then the conversion of the inner part of $2$ would be simpler:

```
  λx.f(f x)
= S (Kf) (K(f x))          (case 3')
= S (Kf) (S (Kf) (Kx))     (case 4)
```

Is the above valid? Are `3'.` and `4.` valid? and is the subsequent conversion valid?

---

Could both be correct? I.e. are their conversion and my conversion, `S (Kf) (S (Kf) I)` and `S (Kf) (S (Kf) (Kx))` respectively, equivalent? I put both expressions through an [online SKI combinator interpreter](http://ski.aditsu.net) and got slightly different things: `(x0->f(f(x0)))` and `(x0->f(f(x)))` respectively. I also applied `y` to both conversions and got different things, `f(fy)` and `f(fx)` respectively:

- `S (Kf) (S (Kf) I) y = f(fy)`

```
  S (Kf) (S (Kf) I) y
= (Kf) y (S (Kf) I y)
= f ((Kf) y (Iy))
= f (f y)
```

- `S (Kf) (S (Kf) (Kx)) y = f(fx)`

```
  S (Kf) (S (Kf) (Kx)) y
= (Kf) y (S (Kf) (Kx) y)
= f ((Kf) y ((Kx) y))
= f (f x)
```

I think that means I've made a mistake in:

3'. `λx.(y z) = S (λx.y) (λx.z) = S (Ky) (Kz)`

or

4. `K(c d) = λx.(c d) = S (Kc) (Kd)`

But I'm not sure where.

Comment: From wikipedia reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus): *S is a substitution operator. It takes three arguments and then returns the first argument applied to the third, which is then applied to the result of the second argument applied to the third.* Unlike rules like substitution it doesn't require y and z must be free of x, so your reference for church numeral 2 is valid. In SKI calculus to replace lambda expressions (bound variables) usually will not end up with mixing terms...

Comment: @mohottnad thanks so much! "so your reference for church numeral 2 is valid." Does "your reference" refer to learnxinyminutes.com? Meaning their conversion is correct? i.e. `2 = S (K f)  (S (K f) I)` is correct?

Comment: correct. I don't find any serious issue, every step with rules sounds reasonable to me at least during the number 2 conversion.

Comment: Follow up question: is their `2. λx.c = Kc` underspecified. Should it require that `c is free of x`? i.e. should it be "`2. λx.c = Kc` provided that c is free of x"?

Comment: I agree c should be regarded as completely independent from x here in 2, but again same as in 3. it can have x as free variable. eg. c=x+1. Since we have Kxy=x by definition, we have Kcy=K(x+1)y=x+1=c. It's helpful to think of K is of function type c→y→c here...

Comment: Though their solution is correct, I tend to like to do a "peephole optimization" of $\lambda x . f x$ to $f$, so you could get a simpler answer of `S (K f) f`.  (Or alternatively, use an "eta-equivalence" to simplify `S (K f) I` to `f` in general.)

Comment: So then, on the next step to abstract `f`, you would eventually get `S (S (K S) K) I`.

Comment: @DanielSchepler thanks. Not sure I understand. Does `S (K f) f` correspond to .? to .()? I applied `x` to `S (K f) f` and got `f(fx)`, so `S (K f) f` corresponds to .(), but I don't follow how you got `S (K f) f` in the first place.